# ordinary differential equation with deviating/distributed/retarded arguments

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How could I approach a differential equation of the following form ($t$ is the independent variable, $s$ is a known constant):
$$
u'(t)=-\frac{1}{s}[u(t-s)-u(t)-s^{2}]
$$
$t-s$ is apparently a deviating or distributed argument, and the differential equation is of the "retarded" type (because $u(t-s)$ lags behind $u(t)$). While googling this I found the following link: [ODE with distributed arguments](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Differential_equations,_ordinary,_with_distributed_arguments) but it doesn't describe the case where $s$ turns up again outside the function $u$. I actually know the solution for this equation. It is $u(t)=t^{2}$. I want to learn from this more simple example to solve the more difficult equation
$$
u'(t)=-\frac{1}{s}\left[u(t-s)-u(t)-(t-s)\ln\frac{t-s}{s}\right]
$$

Comment: Since $s$ is a constant it is not clear what you mean by when $s$ turns up outside $u$? One way of looking at it would be to view the delayed version of $u$ as an input. So the above would be the ODE $u' = {1 \over s} u +s -{1 \over s} \delta$, where $\delta$ is the delayed version. The initial condition must be a function defined on some interval of length $s$, so you could 'solve' it by colving on successive intervals of length $s$.

Comment: copper.hat, in the first equation, s turns up in the factor 1/s and as s^2; it is not only in the argument for the function u in u(t-s). That's why it's not a differential equation of the type u'(t)=F(t,u(t),u(t,s)), which is addressed in the link that I provided. Rather, this differential equation is of the form u'(t)=F(t,s,u(t),u(t,s)), and I don't know what to do. I wasn't able to follow your idea using \delta.

Comment: copper.hat, now I understand your suggestion with \delta. However, I need a solution for this on an interval of validity including both u(t) and u(t-s). In my application both t and t-s are variable between 0 and 1, and ideally I would get a general solution for the interval [0,1].